# nGINX / Angular 4 HTTP 1st load performance

Tags: angular, nginx

I have one angular4 App deployed and linked to NGINX, the problem is.

1. If I open the web application locally on the server, it's working very fast | ex : localhost:80
2. If I open the web application from my client machine it takes a long time in the first load/opening more than 1 minute, and after that, it seems fine.

any suggestions to improve NGINX first load performance?

nginx/1.14.0
Angular 4

```js
proxy_cache_path /alf/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m max_size=20g inactive=50000m use_temp_path=off;

server {
#    listen 80 http2;
#    server_name localhost;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

   location / {
#      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
       proxy_cache my_cache;
       root   /var/www/html/bluemortar;
      index  index.html index.htm;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
#        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
         root   /var/www/html/bluemortar;

    }
```

Comment: And why do you think this is nginx's fault? My 1st guess would be the bundle sizes of your app and the network connection.